# Minecraft Double Switch Door

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to make a base with a hidden door that can be opened from the inside and outside. I was wondering if there was a way of making a circuit that could be operated from two different switches allowing me to operate the door from the inside and outside.
Here is a picture that shows the hidden door in its open status.[image]Sorry its a bit blurred, but hopefully you can see what's happening.

Comment: Instead of using a camera to take a picture of your screen (which results in blurry images as above), you should use print screen instead in the future! (You can either use the `Prt Scr` button on your keyboard (if you have one) or some screen clipping software)

Comment: Or, use Minecraft's built-in screenshot system. Just hit F2.

Comment: I would but i cant find where it saves the pictures

Comment: Normally, it just saves them to your minecraft folder under "screenshots".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an [XOR circuit](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Circuits/Logic#XOR_Gate_.28.E2.8A.BB.29).

An XOR circuit allows either switch to change the state of the door (open/closed). This means the door can be opened or closed using either switch and it doesn't matter if the other switch is up or down.

I have done this but it can be tedious trying to get the Redstone to laid out correctly. In the diagram in the link A would represent a switch on one side of the door and B would represent a the switch on the other side.

Comment: This image might also be on use to you http://i.stack.imgur.com/WIhcQ.png

Comment: The easiest Redstone XOR gate to create IMO is the "F" style on the wiki, because it's only 1 block high.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, concealed, even though my T flip-flop is huge. I put it above the ceiling in a "gatehouse" and then built another floor above it. The wall was also hollow, so I had a button inside, then a bit of redstone in the hollow part, then a button on the outside, and a line of redstone going up to the flip-flop. That way either button will open or close the doors